# Add prgramatically heads to a table

Tags: javascript, json, foreach, html-table

I can retrieve json data and put them programmatically into a table. Here you have the code that you can run. My problem is how can I add the heads programmatically?
Here you can find the code perfectly running LINK [Codepen Code](https://codepen.io/mauro99/full/PoZMJoP)

```
function search() {
    var queryURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

    fetch(queryURL)
            .then(response=> response.json())
            .then(data=>displayUsersAsATable(data))
               .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error during fetch: ' + error.message);
            });
}

function displayUsersAsATable(data) {
 
    var usersDiv = document.querySelector("#users");
    usersDiv.innerHTML = "";

    // creates and populate the table with users
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    data.forEach(function (currentUser) {
  
      var myhead = table.createTHead();
      myhead.innerHTML = "Table Heading"
      
      var mycaption = table.createCaption();
        mycaption.innerHTML = "Table Caption"
  
        var row = table.insertRow();
        var nameCell = row.insertCell();
        nameCell.innerHTML = currentUser.email;
        var cityCell = row.insertCell();
        cityCell.innerHTML = currentUser.address.city;
    });
    
        // adds the table to the div
        usersDiv.appendChild(table);
    }
```

Comment: What is a head ? Can you clarify what that means ?

Comment: HTML <thead> element defines a set of rows defining the head of the columns of the table

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) reference, we cannot use table API such as **insertCell** to insert `<th>` tags in HTML. But it can be achieved programmatically by creating the element using document.createElement and inserting it.

In the code you shared table header creation is included in the loop which will result in the header being created for each data. So I have moved the head creation outside the loop assuming this must be the case.

Related snippet:

```js
   var myhead = table.createTHead();
   var headRow = myhead.insertRow();
   var emailHead = document.createElement('th');
   var nameHead = emailHead.cloneNode();
   headRow.appendChild(emailHead);
   headRow.appendChild(nameHead);
   emailHead.innerHTML = 'Email';
   nameHead.innerHTML = 'Name';
```

Working Demo:

```js
function search() {
    var queryURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

    fetch(queryURL)
            .then(response=> response.json())
          //arrow function by Mauro - works fine!
            .then(data=>displayUsersAsATable(data))
               .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error during fetch: ' + error.message);
            });
}

//questa è una variazione

function displayUsersAsATable(data) {
    // users is a JavaScript object

    // empty the div that contains the results
    var usersDiv = document.querySelector("#users");
    usersDiv.innerHTML = "";
  
    // creates and populate the table with users
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var mycaption = table.createCaption();
    mycaption.innerHTML = "Table Caption"
    
    //Creating and populating table header.
    var myhead = table.createTHead();
    var headRow = myhead.insertRow();
    var emailHead = document.createElement('th');
    var nameHead = emailHead.cloneNode();
    headRow.appendChild(emailHead);
    headRow.appendChild(nameHead);
    emailHead.innerHTML = 'Email';
    nameHead.innerHTML = 'Name';
  
    var tableBody = table.createTBody();
  
    // iterate on the array of users
    data.forEach(function (currentUser) {
      //inserimento dei titoli della colonna programmaticamente
        // creates a row
        var row = tableBody.insertRow();
        // insert cells in the row
        var nameCell = row.insertCell();
        nameCell.innerHTML = currentUser.email;
        var cityCell = row.insertCell();
        cityCell.innerHTML = currentUser.address.city;
    });

    // adds the table to the div
    usersDiv.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
table {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid;
background-color: rgb(200, 200, 100);
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Working with remote data</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <!-- Polyfill in case your browser does not support the fetch API -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/0.10.1/fetch.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="search();">Get remote list of users' names and emails using the fetch API</button>
  <div id="users"></div>
</body>
```